# Installing RMySQL package when MySQL is installed in other drivers except C:\?

Tags: mysql, r, rmysql

R version `3.0.2 (2013-09-25)` 
Platform: `x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)`

I've used RMySQL since , and recently I formatted my computer and now
trying to install RMySQL again.
But in this time, I installed MySQL Server on other hard drive, not on `C:\`
I did everything i know, the things when installing RMySQL before,
and I got the result like this on R-studio console.

```
(I installed MySQL Server on E:, and installed R, Rtools, Rstudio on C:)
```

...

```
Error : .onLoad failed in loadNamespace() for 'RMySQL', details:
  call: fun(libname, pkgname)
  error: Cannot find a suitable MySQL install
ERROR: loading failed
```

...

Comment: It shouldn't matter which drive has MySQL.   Just set up MYSQL_HOME appropriately.

Comment: G.Grothendieck// I've already tried to change all paths to change E: including Renviron, MYSQL_HOME, and etc, but it didn't work

Comment: I assumed you did these things since you mention you had it working before but double check that you are using the distribution from th mysql site, that MySQL works without R, that you have copied any dll files in %MYSQL_HOME%\lib to %MYSQL_HOME%\bin, that you have rebuilt RMySQL with the new setup (and are not using a previously built RMySQL) and also check it with Rgui.

Comment: I recently checked these answers. thanks pretty much anyway. I figured it out somehow myself at that time. :)